# Add value to variable PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, variables, categories

I am creating a category list.. 20 different categories and when they click and send a category it will pass a numeric value representing the category to the Database..

For example:

`<option value="1">Apple</option>`
`<option value="2">Microsoft</option>`

The reason for that I am passing a numeric value in the database, is because I have more than 1 language on the webpage, and I have different label files. I would like to echo a php variable based on the category number.

`<? echo $ct_1; ?>`

But to avoid a lot of if/else statements, I would like to know if I could add the number to the variable. So if I am looping the category to be this: `$row['category']` I would like to add that variable to the other one.. Like so:

`<? $category = $.'ct_'.$row['category']; echo $category; ?>`

I know that is not possible.. But I hope you get my idea and maybe have a solution for this.

Comment: Actually that *is* possible. You only need to read it up in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$category = ${'ct_'.$row['category']};
echo $category;
```

Or just:

```
echo ${'ct_'.$row['category']};
```

Comment: This is just perfect! :D Great thanks!!! Works right away, and exactly what I needed... Thanks for the quick response.. I just knew that it couldn't be that difficult.. I have tried to do it myself but I used '()' and '[]' instead of '{}'.. Just look at that.. I was very close :p

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: Glad I could help :-D  Yeah, the `{}` are used to create strings on-the-fly in PHP.  The `{}` can also be used in objects `$obj->{'prop-name'.$x}`.

Answer (score 3):

A tailored [variable variable<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) example:

```
<?php $category = 'ct_'.$row['category']; echo $$category; ?>
```

If you look closely it's nearly identival to yours:

```
<?php $category = $.'ct_'.$row['category']; echo $category; ?>
                  ^                              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You COULD use eval() but that can lead to some very big security holes.

I suggest using an array instead:

```
$ct = array(1 => "Apple", 2 => "Microsoft");
echo $ct[$row['category']];
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty approach would be to use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
eval('$category = $ct_'. $row['category'] . ';');
echo $category;
```

Make sure input is sanitized first!

Comment: And you make sure to actually return something :)